# Problem in Wine with Kurdish fonts

Tags: wine, 15.04, fonts, winetricks

when I install Wine on Ubuntu 15.04 I have a problem with my fonts.

I have downloaded all Winetricks fonts, but this has not fixed my font problem.

How can I remove all Wine fonts? Or how can I fix my problem?

I want my fonts back to the way they were before I installed Wine.

This is the picture of my problem:

[image]

Sorry for my bad English, thanks :)

Comment: Could you please explain your problem with the fonts?

Comment: see this photo, this is my problem, after download wine my fonts crashed :/
http://i.imgur.com/9MI9I9R.png

Comment: Ahh ok, it's more clear now :)

Comment: how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all fonts from the `/usr/local/share/wine/fonts` and `/usr/local/share/fonts` directories.

[source](http://wine-wiki.org/index.php/Fonts#Blank_boxes)

Comment: idon't see{ /usr/local/share/wine/fonts } folder

Comment: and {/usr/local/share/fonts} no have any fonts  :/ :(

Comment: ohh i see wine fonts but i can't delete it -_-

Comment: i delete it but not fix my problem :3